# Erlang causes page faults

Tags: erlang, page-fault

When I run the script described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005759/erlang-on-multicore-cpu) with my user, everything is well:

```
lorenzo@enzo:~/erlang/pei$ time erl -noshell -smp enabled -S 4 -s fib4 main 10000000

real    0m54.952s
user    1m16.090s
sys 0m0.070s
```

When I run it as root, it crashed:

```
lorenzo@enzo:~/erlang/pei$ sudo time erl -noshell -smp enabled -S 4 -s fib4 main 10000000
[sudo] password for lorenzo: 
74.68user 0.04system 0:53.56elapsed 139%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 66064maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+8306minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

The error is reproduceable.

**My questions are:**

- Can someone try to explain me what is happending there?
- Is it a problem with the erlang runtime or with my OS?
- Can someone reproduce this error?

I am running erlang 5.7.4 on ubuntu natty with kernel

```
Linux enzo 2.6.38-10-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 15:07:17 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

on a Phenom X4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you think it crashed? `time` just shows more info when running as root. [Page fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault) is not an error but just the way [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) works.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the two runs is that in the first run, you're running the shell builtin `time`, but in the second run, you're running whatever `sudo` finds in the path, which is `/usr/bin/time`.  These two tools have different output formats.

```
$ type time
time is a shell keyword
$ time echo


real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
$ type /usr/bin/time
/usr/bin/time is /usr/bin/time
$ /usr/bin/time echo

0.01user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 1000%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2784maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+217minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```